The two versions of the Axiom of Infinity in Zermelo set theory (not Zermelo–Fraenkel)
In Zermelo's original axioms (call this theory ZC) the axiom of infinity is (in translation)

"There exists in the domain at least one set $Z$ that contains the null set as an element and is so constituted that to each of its elements $a$ there corresponds a further element of the form $\{a\}$, in other words, that with each of its elements $a$ it also contains the corresponding set $\{a\}$ as element."

Following this question (in the context of ZF), call this axiom 'Infinity 2' The Wikipedia page later says

The axiom of infinity is usually now modified to assert the existence of the first infinite von Neumann ordinal $\omega$; the original Zermelo axioms cannot prove the existence of this set, nor can the modified Zermelo axioms prove Zermelo's axiom of infinity.

Call the axiom that $\omega$ is a set 'Infinity 1'. There's no citation for this 'now usually modified' claim. Write ZC' for ZC with 'Infinity 1' instead of Zermelo's original 'Infinity 2'.
It is not wholly clear in one of the directions, but this seems to say that over Axioms I-VI on the Wikipedia page, neither of the two axioms of infinity can prove the other. How exactly does this work? (a reference would be good, to update the page)
Is at least one of them because the rank of the particular infinite set is too large, and so is not in the model $V_{\omega+\omega}$? (for that matter, this is usually claimed to be a model of Zermelo set theory - but which one? ZC or ZC'?)
What might one gain in using 'Infinity 1' over 'Infinity 2', in the context of a Replacementless axiom system? I'm not generally perturbed by the lack of very many von Neumann ordinals, I'm happy to use general well-orderings, so I don't want an answer like "you get the usual ordinals!".

This independence is the result of the note "Les axiomes de l'infini dans la théorie des ensembles sans axiome de substitution" by Jean Drabbe,
Comptes Rendus de I' Acadjmie des Sciences, Paris, vol. 268 (1969), p. 137. (BnF)
Unfortunately, no proof is given. it is only stated that this can be shown with methods of the paper "Axiome et schéma de fondement dans la système de Zermelo" by Maurice Boffa which supposedly was published in the Bulletin L'Académie Polonaise des Science, Série des Sciences Mathématiques.
I could not find this paper online. The following argument works though (I do not know how close this is to Boffa's argument):
Suppose we live in a ZF universe. Whenever $X$ is a non-empty set so that for $x \in X$ there is $y\in X$ with $x\in y$ then $M_X=\{a\mid x\nsubseteq\mathrm{tc}(a)\}$ is a model of Zermelo set theory, except maybe the axioms of Pairing and Infinity. Here, $\mathrm{tc}(a)$ is the transitive closure of $a$.
Let $\omega^\ast$ denote the Zermelo version of $\omega$, i.e. the smallest set witnessing Infinity2. One can check that

both $M_\omega$ and $M_{\omega^\ast}$ are models of Pairing,
$M_\omega\models \mathrm{Infinity 2}\wedge \neg\mathrm{Infinity 1}$ and
$M_{\omega^\ast}\models \mathrm{Infinity 1}\wedge \neg\mathrm{Infinity 2}$,

so we are done.
I do not believe there is a serious mathemtical advantage of one of these axioms over the other in the context of Zermelo set theory. Even if $\omega$ exists, Zermelo set theory does not guarantee that $\omega+\omega$ exists and similar for the Zermelo-version of these ordinals. In any case, if either $\omega$ or $\omega^\ast$ exists then the other one is coded in a reasonable way as a subset of the first one. Making this more precise should lead to an equiconsistency of the two formulations of Zermelo Set Theory.
We have simply (and rightfully so) standardized what the axiom of Infinity is and there is no mathematical reason to keep the old one due to Zermelo around.

In any case, if either $\omega$ or $\omega^*$ exists then the other one is coded in a reasonable way as a subset of the first one. <-- can you say more? How do you mean encoded? (Also, in your definition of $M_X$, I think there is a typo)
